# What upper bound can we get under 3-wise independence? (comparable edition)

Tags: randomized-algorithms, upper-bounds, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators

Here is the original question: [What bound can we get using $k$-th moment inequality under 3-wise independence?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17985/what-bound-can-we-get-using-kth-moment-inequality-under-3-wise-independent) .Yury has given a 3-wise independent example that shows the upper bound is no better than $O(1/t)$.

There is another way to constructing 3-wise independent variables (see more details in http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PS/RND/l03.ps). Are they essentially equal to each other, particularly on deriving the upper bound of $\Pr(|\sum_i(X_i)-\mu|\geq t)$?

Here is the main idea of the construction:
We sample 3 random variables ${r_1,r_2,r_3}$ from $[m]$ uniformly and independently ($m$ is a prime). Then we construct a set $\Omega = \{r_1+r_2*i+r_3*i^2\mod m:i \in [m]\}$. The elements are 3-wise independent. Does the sum of these variables get a similar upper bound?

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: I updated it. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: So is the question whether this particular construction of 3-wise independent bits has good concentration? i.e. better concentration bounds than 2-wise independence. Rather general 3-wise independent distributions, as asked in the original question.

Comment: In fact I'm asking what the essential information can we get from 3-wise independence. Comparing the bounds derived from these two constructions may be enlightening.

Comment: What is $m$? Do your random variables take values in $\{0,1\}$ or in $[m]$? Is $\Omega$ the probability space or the set of random variables indexed by $i$?

Comment: Random variables take values in $[m]$. $\Omega$ is the set of random variables.

Comment: But Yury's previous answer already tells you that for the purposes of tail bounds, 3-wise independence itself doesn't tell you anything beyond 2-wise independence. Why do you want to go into a specific construction? Why do you care so much about 3-wise independence in particular. This question seems unmotivated to me.

Comment: @SashoNikolov sounds like you're reviewing this for a conference :).

Comment: @Suresh lol it does..no more commenting late at night. in a less snappy tone: it feels like OP has some other goal in mind and if he does, it will be more productive if he articulates it.